# asp.net MVC Read URL Query parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, post, .net-core

I am relatively new to dotnet core, I am trying to read an Id value from the url using `[FromQuery]` attribute but it keeps coming in as a 0.

I am making a `POST` request to "/api/Sponsors/UploadImage/-1"

here is my action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadImage/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadSponsorImageAsync([FromQuery] int id, IFormFile file)
    { 
      if (id == -1)
      {
       //something
      }
      else{
        //something else
      }
    }
```

[image: request details]

**Id is always 0** at the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always 0 because that's the default value for a number in C#.  You are not passing a query string in your url that is the problem, so the default is 0.

Your URL should look like this...

**/api/sponsors/uploadimage?id=1**